# Not able to read data from Perforce using python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, perforce, perforce-client-spec, perforce-integrate

Please help me read data/file from Perforce.
I have tried to use the below code to read the file from Perforce using this python script.

The same code works fine in Python shell, even when executing step by step in pycharm it works perfectly.

```
# copy the file from the P4 to the local computer
def getp4file(outfile,errfile,path):

    path = 'p4 print ' + path
    with open(outfile, "wb") as out, open(errfile, "wb") as err:
        subprocess.Popen(path, stdout=out, stderr=err)
    out.close()
    err.close()
    return


getp4file('config.txt', 'err.txt', 'path_of_the_file')
```

Comment: Does anything get printed into config.txt or err.txt?

Comment: Your code works fine for me (note that your usage of `subprocess.Popen` is platform-dependent; it'd be better to use `subprocess.Popen(['p4', 'print', path], stdout=out, stderr=err)`), so you'll need to provide more details, particularly the contents of `err.txt`. (Is `path_of_the_file` a depot path? a relative path? absolute?)

Comment: Just added a delay and things worked.

Delay of 5 seconds before return statement

Answer (score 0):

Just added a delay and things worked.

Delay of 5 seconds before return statement